# How to get the data from ajax in controller codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have an editable table in my view.. At first, there's no data in the table but the user can add data in the table since it is editable. And there's no exact number of rows in the table since I have also a button that can add new row. I want to get the data that the user have added and save it in the database.

I have this code:

VIEW:

```
 <table class="table " id="memberTB">
    <thead><tr><th >First Name</th><th >Middle Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
                   <tr id="first"><td><span class="edit"></span></td>
                   <td><span class="edit"></span></td>
                   <td><span class="edit"></span></td></tr>
    </tbody>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="addrow"><span class="fa fa-plus"> Add new row</span></button>

</table>
<br><button type="button" class="btn" id="savebtn">Save</button> <a href="#" class="btn" id="resetbtn">Reset</a>
```

JS:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
$.fn.editable.defaults.showbuttons = false;
$.fn.editable.defaults.url = '/post';
$.fn.editable.defaults.type = 'text';

// make all items having class 'edit' editable
$('.edit').editable();

    // this is to automatically make the next item in the table editable
$('.edit').on('save', function(e, params){
    var that = this;
    // persist the old value in the element to be restored when clicking reset
    var oldItemValue = $(that)[0].innerHTML;
    if (!$(that).attr('oldValue')) {
        console.log('persisting original value: ' + oldItemValue)
        $(that).attr('oldValue', oldItemValue);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        // first search the row
        var item = $(that).closest('td').next().find('.edit');
        console.log(item);
        if (item.length == 0) {
            // check the next row
            item = $(that).closest('tr').next().find('.edit');
        }
        item.editable('show');
    }, 200);
});

$('#resetbtn').click(function() {
    $('.edit').each(function() {
        var o = $(this);
        o.editable('setValue', o.attr('oldValue'))  //clear values
        .editable('option', 'pk', o.attr('pk')) //clear pk
        .removeClass('editable-unsaved')
        .removeAttr('oldValue');
    });
});


$('#savebtn').click(function() {
    var person = [];
    var x=1;
    $('tbody tr',$('#memberTB')).each(function(){
        for(var i = 0 ; i < cells ; i++)
        {

            person[x][i]=$(this).find('td').eq(i).text();
        }
        x++;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url("index.php/test/Savedata");?>',
        type: "post",
        data: { values: arraylng },
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
});
$('#addrow').click(function() {
    $('#memberTB > tbody:last').append(' <tr><td><span class="edit"></span></td><td><span class="edit"></span></td><td><span class="edit"></span></td></tr>');
    $('.edit').editable();
});
```

Controller: [inside the test.php]

```
public function saveData(){

  $this->load->model('test_model');
  $myArray = $_REQUEST['values'];
  echo sizeof($myArray);
}
```

Whenever I click the save button, there's no response at all.. Where did I go wrong? please help me..

ADDED INFO: 
     I didn't include my SQL insert statement here because I want to test first if there's data in `$myArray` if I added data in the table.

Comment: Is there a reason you have `//ajax emulation` followed by `$.mockjax({` in the JS?

Comment: I deleted it already.. Actually, I just copied it in my reference. And when I tried to delete, it doesn't affect the table.. So now,  I won't include it in the js.. @NathanTuggy

Comment: Have you checked console for errors?

Comment: @siddhesh..No, I haven't checked and I actually don't know how to.. I'm using aptana..

Comment: While testing (Google Chrome recommended) press F12 to get developer panel, go to Console tab and check for JavaScript errors. Can be done in other browsers too, but you need to find how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use this ajax

```
var arraylng = [3,4,7];
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url("index.php/test/Savedata");?>',
    type: "post",
    data: {values: JSON.stringify(arraylng)},
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

arraylng is an array, which doesn't exist in the code. I added it here for debugging.
Suppose you want to send person[] array, you write, data: {values: JSON.stringify(person)}.
Now, the person array may not exist, because of the "i < cells" in for. What is cells?

The word response is just a name, any name, but better avoid 'data'.

In test.php, what is sizeof($myArray)? Just, echo $myArray;

When you click save you must get the $myArray content in an alert.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I got the $myArray content in the alert.. But how can it go to other page? I mean, not just an alert but it will really load the test.php? how can I do that?

Comment: You've got the alert, because in fact test.php has already got the data, and sent it back to the view. Do something with $myArray in saveData() and send it back. You 'll get a different response.  This is what ajax do. What were you expecting? And you don't need to just alert() it. You may manipulate it in your success function.

Comment: ah.. ok. But what if I have an insert function in the test.php?

Comment: can I add an sql insert statement in the success function?

Comment: No. You have the data collected in the html, in the saveData() as a string. $myArray is a string. All you have to do is build the right array structure, in saveData, and then save it. You may make an array out of a string with explode().  The success function 'lays' in the View. In this function you will code, what you want to show at your html page.